# Alternative for the python snippet

Tags: python, numpy

The following snippet causes memory error when dealing with large amount of data.

```
measurer = np.vectorize(len)
res1 = measurer(df_cat.values.astype(str)).max(axis=0)
answer_cat['Maximum']=res1
res2 = measurer(df_cat.values.astype(str)).min(axis=0)
answer_cat['Minimum']=res2
```

Here **answer_cat** is the dataframe, in which all the column data is converted to string type, to find the maximum and minimum length of each column in the dataframe.
Kindly help me with finding an alternative for it

Comment: Have you tried using any form of analytic tools to see what causes this? This would be a great opportunity to learn how to debug simple scripts. Good keywords to search for: [python memory profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/).

Comment: @Torxed This was tried and couldn't find the right answer for it

Comment: Have you tried running a for loop?

Comment: @Divakar Yes I have

Comment: So, still on memory error with loop?

Comment: Where does the memory error occur?  For example is in `df_cat.values.astype(str)`.  If the frame elements include some very long strings this could be the problem, since `astype(str)` makes an array with the maximum string length.  If it works, look at its `dtype`.

Comment: What's the nature of the data in this frame?  Are all columns strings already?  Maybe you don't need to do the `astype(str)`.  The `values` array will already be object dtype with python strings.  How many columns?  rows?  Maybe you could iterate on the columns, and get the max len for each one separately?

Comment: What is `len` in this case? So we can reproduce and experiment ourselves. And how much RAM does your PC have?

Answer (score 0):

For one column (Series) of strings, you don't need `astype(str)`:

```
In [518]: df = pd.Series(['one','two','three'])                                                        
In [519]: df                                                                                           
Out[519]: 
0      one
1      two
2    three
dtype: object
In [520]: df.values                                                                                    
Out[520]: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)
In [521]: [len(i) for i in df.values]                                                                  
Out[521]: [3, 3, 5]
In [522]: max([len(i) for i in df.values])                                                             
Out[522]: 5
In [523]: df.values.astype(str)                                                                        
Out[523]: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype='<U5')
In [524]: [len(i) for i in df.values.astype(str)]                                                      
Out[524]: [3, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't for one column but for all the columns in the dataframe

Comment: But you want the max len for each column, right?  So you could, in theory, iterate on columns and do this calculation one column at a time?   You did not provide a [mcve] so I had to make up a demo case, which gives me the right to keep it simple and to the point.  You are having memory problems when using all columns at once!